# Why is the directional light illuminating the box placed behind it?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've added a `DirectionalLightHelper` to my code to illuminate a box. The light is placed at coordinates (2,2,1) and two boxes at (0,0,0) and (3,3,3). The box at (3,3,3) shouldn't be illuminated by the directionalLight, yet it is being illuminated the same way the box at (0,0,0) is. Any insight on this would be really helpful.

Scene Image Here

[image: 1]

Comment: Why do you think it should not be illuminated? Have you implemented the shadow map correctly? Without a shadow map, the light is not blocked by objects.

Answer (score 1):

DirectionalLight doesn’t behave like a panel of light.

[From the docs:](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=direction#api/en/lights/DirectionalLight)

> light will behave as though it is infinitely far away and the rays produced from it are all parallel.

So when you assign it’s position, it’s actually the vector from where the light rays are coming from, and it’ll affect all objects on the scene.

Maybe you’d like to use [layers](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=layers#api/en/core/Layers) so the light only affects one box but not the other.